# how to stop a CountBLANK formula changing when adding a row to

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel doc with a Formula that counts the total Blank cells. and the output is used to change colors on tabs. my Issue is that when i insert or delete a row the formula either adds or removes a row

i need to count blank rows in column F10 to F100 only. But when i add a row this formula changes to F10:F101 and i cant seem to stop this. I have tried Absolute references but it still changes. This formula is in only one cell so i dont see why its changing
see Code Below
=COUNTBLANK(F10:F100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OFFSET to reference exactly 91 cells beginning with F10

```
=COUNTBLANK(OFFSET($F$10,0,0,91,1))
```

OFFSET creates a new range based on a given range (the first argument. The 2nd and 3rd arguments are the offset (in rows and columns) from the given range. The 4th and 5th arguments are the height and width of the new range.

Because the height of the range is hard coded as 91, it will not change when rows are added.